# C3p0 connection pool size increasing randomly for each call

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am working on middleware technology Hibernate in that for increasing connection efficiency i used **c3po** and i have configured the following parameters but while during each call ti the service the connection pool size increasing randomly without control and each time its increasing connection without using previous connection which is opened and remaining idle below i have proivided the  configuration parameters , kindly tell me what i miss to configure

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">3600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">4</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>'
```

Comment: Look here for [c3p0 & hibernate](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#hibernate-specific), especially `hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=30 hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true`

Comment: Can you post your full data layer configuration. Maybe you override these settings in your Spring configuration.

Answer (score 3):

One common mistake using connection pooling is forgetting to `close` the connection once you have finished with it. Generally, a connection pool system such as C3PO wraps the real connection in a proxy and redirects the `close` method to perform a release to the pool.

Without more details of your code it is difficult to say what your problem is but this is certainly a common mistake - I made it too the first time I used a connection pool.

In brief - **remember to `close` your connections when you've finished with it**.

The pattern you should be using should be something like:

```
Connection connection;
try {
  connection = getConnection();
  ...
} finally {
  if ( connection != null ) {
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @ OldCurmudgeon But i have provided  'session.close' in each service what else i have to do

Comment: @Vicky - If you definitely close your connections **everywhere** then this may not be your issue - see JoopEggen's comment for a way to find your issue.

Comment: Close connection means just closing session or closing session factory by getSessionFactory.close

Comment: @Vicky - That is a `Hibernate` question, not a `C3P0` question. I doubt you should close the factory though.

Comment: I will try and let u know Thanks